# 'React' is not defined react/jsx-no-undef

Tags: reactjs

I have started following this beginners video tutorial for reactJs. The link is [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gY5sGvq-8h8&t=1610s](https://stackoverflow.com). I am getting 'React' is not defined error.

The following files which are i am using :
a) App.js

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Navbar from './Components/NavBar';

function App() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Navbar />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default App;
```

b) Navbar.js

```
import React from 'react';

class Navbar extends React.Component{
    render() { 
        return (
            <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-body-tertiary">
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <a className="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
          <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span className="navbar-toggler-icon" />
          </button>
          <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul className="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
              <li className="nav-item">
                <a className="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <a className="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item dropdown">
                <a className="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                  Dropdown
                </a>
                <ul className="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a className="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                  <li><a className="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                  <li><hr className="dropdown-divider" /></li>
                  <li><a className="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <a className="nav-link disabled" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <form className="d-flex" role="search">
              <input className="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" />
              <button className="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>

        );
    }
}
 
export default Navbar;
```

Please guide me where i am doing wrong.

I tried to search the error on google, but not able to solve it.
I am getting this error in Navbar.js

Comment: You need `import React from 'react';` in every file that uses JSX

Comment: @mousetail it worked like a magic. Thanks for your valuable comment.